# Decoding a Protobuf response

Tags: protocol-buffers

[image]

For the above response, I am trying to write a message but I can't decode it. This screenshot is from Charles proxy. Here is what I have tried so far:

```proto
syntax = "proto2";

message SingleSearchContainer {
  optional string SearchHtmlContent = 7;
}

message UnknownField {
  optional SingleSearchContainer singleContainer = 101;
}

message SingleSearch {
  optional UnknownField unknownField = 2;
}

message SearchResults {
  repeated string SearchResult = 1;
}
```

And this results in this error:

```sh
google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message
```

What might I be doing wrong here?

Comment: You appear to have four field IDs in your definitions and a lot more in your actual messages. Where are the missing definitions?

Comment: @paxdiablo Is this mandatory to define all fields even if we don't need them? I'm really sorry as I'm new to protobuf and as this decoding is required in a single project, I didn't spend too much time learning protocol buffers.

Comment: Rehmat, I'm not sure since we always have up-to-date (synchronised) definitions in our system. I suspect it may not since I know it can handle message version disconnects between the two ends such as if, for example, you add another optional field at sender - the receiver just ignores it, I think. My comment wasn't so much a method of fixing the problem as it was a way to make debugging the problem substantially easier. From the data dump, all of your known fields (1, 2, 7, 101) appear to be sub-fields of things that PB does *not* know the definition off.

Comment: My advice, therefore, is to do the full definitions and see if that fixes it. Or, at a *minimum,* do the definitions required to get from the top level down to the fields you're interested in.

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance. I'll try your suggestions and will see if that works.